# How to eliminate delays accessing shared network folders?

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming

I am developing a C# library which requires access to shared network folders (distributed over LAN). If I use mapped drives then the access to the location (e.g. Z:\Shared) is usually instantaneous, however if I use the IP address (e.g. \\192.168.1.3\Shared) there is a considerable delay.

For my project it is a lot easier to deploy using IP addresses from configuration, if anyone could comment on why the delay is occurring or how to eliminate it I would be very grateful.

Comment: The only difference is the lookup of the IP address on the DNS server.  When you transfer LARGE files is there a significant difference in transfer time? I suspect there may be a initial delay of up to 5 seconds for the lookup but the transfer time should be about the same.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17888107/faster-way-to-access-a-file-on-a-windows-7-network-share